# How to get all files in time frame in Linux | C#

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, filesystems

I've been struggling a bit with this one.

I have a Linux based proccess in C#, in which In it want to filter files that there content was written in a given time frame (start time and end time).
When I've done it on Windows it was relativly easy since I have the file creation time and the last write time, so I could check the time range in the folllowing logic:

`fileCreationTimeUtc <= timeFrameUtc.EndTime && lastWriteTimeUtc >= timeFrameUtc.StartTime;`

The issue is that on Linux I can't get the creation time of a file (at least not straight forward like in windows via the `FileInfo` class), and the creation time is equal the to last write time, so I don't know how I can achive such logic.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why wouldn't Linux also give you the same date values as Windows?

Comment: @gunr2171 the filesystem doesn't store the CreationTime timestamp out of the box, you'll have to use external tools and even when you do so there is no guaranty. You can look here for more info https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created